# XAMPP - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

09:43:49 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
09:43:49 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
09:43:53 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

### mysql_error.log

InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-09-17 13:22:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-17 13:22:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-09-17 13:22:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-09-17 13:22:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-17 13:22:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-17 13:22:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-17 13:22:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-17 13:22:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 294606; transaction id 138
2019-09-17 13:22:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-17 13:22:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-17 13:22:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.

Answer (score 0):

is your mysql port blocked? i need a bit more context for this
put in your mysql port for xampp [here](https://canyouseeme.org/), if you haven't port forwarded do it already, there's a tutorial for every different isp